# Apache Tomcat 8.5.5., not able to start application when set unpackWARs="false"

Tags: tomcat

I am using Apache Tomcat 8.5.5, and set unpackWARs="false" and autodeploy = "true" in server.xml file, but once server started, although deployables are not unpacked in webapps folder of Apache tomcat but application does not start.

Basically my requirement is there should be no unpacked war but application or module should be up after tomcat starts.

Exception observed is -
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /$TOMCAT_PATH$/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/‌​jxl.jar (No such file or directory)

Comment: Can you please add the error log which you are getting?

Comment: The exception observed is 
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /$TOMCAT_PATH$/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jxl.jar (No such file or directory).